# Div real auto width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div which is basically a grid of `float: left` smaller divs. I want the whole grid to have an auto width and that it will be centered relatively to its container. The `display: inline-block` to grid + `text-align: center` to container doesn't produce the desired result.
It seems that once populating the grid with several divs such that a new row is created, the gird's width is maximized to container's width even if the smaller divs are not fit exactly to the row and there is some white space remaining at the right.

What is the solution?[image]

Comment: Can you mix in some <span> to format it correctly?

Comment: I think you'll need to specify a width on your container.

Answer (score 1):

Why `float` your smaller `div`s in the first place? Using `display: inline-block;` on them gives you much more control when it comes to centering, and enables you to make the container `width` 'auto' by doing `display: inline-block;` as well. Here's a little working demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/4JbUJ/).

Here's the basic outline, HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "floatcontainer">
        <img src = "" alt = "" class = "floatimg"/>
        <img src = "" alt = "" class = "floatimg"/>
        <img src = "" alt = "" class = "floatimg"/>
        <br/>
        <img src = "" alt = "" class = "floatimg"/>
        <img src = "" alt = "" class = "floatimg"/>
        <img src = "" alt = "" class = "floatimg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.floatimg {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
}
.floatcontainer {
    display: inline-block; /*makes the div's width only as large as needed*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: I was thinking there should be only 3 div's per line, it's hard to tell from the description.

Comment: @tsergium Well, one can force each line to have 3 `div`s by adding `white-space: nowrap;`. I hope @user1639431 can clarify what he has in mind exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use tables here, but if that's not the case try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLdGp/1/) I made.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Demo


    
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
    

​

**CSS**

```
.container{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.item{
        height: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 2%;
        width: 32%;
        float: left;
        background-color: #dfdfdf;
    }
    .mr0{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .clear{
        clear: both;
    }
    ​
```

Comment: I don't think the `div`s are centered in your demo, they just have a width `32%`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it simple and use

```
div.big {
width:100%;
}
div.small {
    width:33.33%
}
```